# How to manage different environments using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I’m currently using cloudformation(JSON template) to manage different aws services.
The Aws services I use include S3, Lambda, API Gateway, Amplify, Dynamodb, IAM, Cognito.

The development phase is almost finished, now I'm finding ways to build UAT environments by using the existing cloudformation template.

Different ways come into my mind.

1.Create cloudformation stacks after switching to different countries

> But some services like S3 are cross-country services.
> If I create another S3 bucket with the same name, the bucket might not be successfully created.

2.Create new IAM User for creating cloudformation stacks

> I am currently using the Root User account for the Service Management in the development stage(I know it's bad practise though).
>  I can create a new IAM user(e.g. UAT_Admin) to create the UAT environment.

These are all methods I can think of. I need a method for the environment management for later creating UAT environments,
 and even the Production environment in the future.
Any comments or suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For greatest separation of different development environments (dev, testing, uat, prod) often different accounts are used. This provides **greatest separation of resources** without risking that someone from testing will accidentally delete/modify production services.

To make it easier to work with different accounts AWS provides [AWS Organizations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_introduction.html) as well as [AWS CloudFormation StackSets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/what-is-cfnstacksets.html). The StackSets would enable you to use same template accorss different accounts.

Comment: What is the difference if I just run create-stack again in other account?

Comment: Also, can I just create IAM account for UAT/production environments?

Comment: @CCCC StackSets is central place for management of stacks in different regions and accounts. You don't have to use it if you prefer not to. You can create any number of accounts you want in AWS organization.

Comment: Aws doc: “Note that your template updates always affect all stacks; you cannot selectively update the template for some stacks in the stack set, but not others.” It means if I aim to test development environment and change the template, the UAT and Production environments will also change?

Comment: @CCCC Yes. If you want to keep them independent, then you can do it separately as you wrote before.

Comment: Which one should I use? creating new IAM user or creating new user via AWS Organization?

Comment: @CCCC it's up to you. There is no one approach to be suitable for all possible use cases. If you require greater separation between different environments, then you should use different accounts. If not, then use different regions, VPCs or iam users.